# na.value can not work in scale_fill_continuous() in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to set the color of NA value.

But it does not work when I set `scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'red')`.

Reproducible example like this:

```
df = data.frame(
  grade = c('class 1', 'class 1', 'class 2'),
  sex   = c('Female', 'Male', 'Female'),
  n     = c(1,5,3))
df

df %>% ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = grade, fill = n)) +
  geom_tile()

df %>% ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = grade, fill = n)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'red')
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `NA` value in the data, you need to first generate it and then use the plotting code.

One way to generate the missing combination is to use `tidyr::complete`.

```
library(ggplot2)

tidyr::complete(df, grade, sex) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = grade, fill = n)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I checked the `complete` document.*For factors, the full set of levels (not just those that appear in the data) are used.* There is still a little question. How  can I complete a factor vector just those that appear in the data.  For example, `df$grade = factor(df$grade, levels =c('class 1', 'class 2', 'class 3'))`

Comment: Make it to character `df$grade <- as.character(df$grade)`